# ¿Consulta de tipo JOIN con 2 bases de datos SQL server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo una comparacion entre 2 tablas del mismo nombre con PHP de una base de datos en SQL SERVER

```
 <?php 

    $sql = "SELECT ITM1.ItemCode, OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName, ITM1.Price, ITM1.PriceList FROM OITM, ITM1 WHERE ITM1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode AND ITM1.PriceList=1 ORDER BY ITM1.ItemCode" ;
    $sql2 = "SELECT ITM1.ItemCode, .OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName, ITM1.Price, ITM1.PriceList FROM OITM, ITM1 WHERE ITM1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode AND ITM1.PriceList=1 ORDER BY ITM1.ItemCode ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn_sisT, $sql );
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn_sisM, $sql2 );

       if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
       if( $stmt2 === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }

        while ( $rowT = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
              while ($rowM = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $itemcode = $rowM['ItemCode'];

                 if (array_search($itemcode,$rowT)) {//son iguales

                 if ($rowT['Price']==$rowM['Price']) {//mismo precio
                        $p=$rowT['Price']+0;
                        echo "<tr><td>".$rowT['ItemCode']."  </td><td> ".$rowT['ItemName']." </td><td> ".$p." MXN </td>   </tr>";
                        break;  
}
if ($rowT['Price']!=$rowM['Price']) {

$p=$rowT['Price']+0;
echo "<tr><td>".$rowT['ItemCode']."  </td><td> ".$rowT['ItemName']." </td><td style='color:red;'> ".$p." MXN MASTER: ".$rowM['Price']."</td></tr>";
break; 
    }
 }
else {
$p=$rowT['Price']+0;
$m=$rowM['Price']+0;
echo "<tr><td>".$rowT['ItemCode']." | ".$rowM['ItemCode']."  
</td><td> ".$rowT['ItemName']." | ".$rowM['ItemName']." 
</td><td> ".$p." MXN | ".$m." MXN</td>  </tr>";
break; 
 }

}
}

?>
```

el Problema es que compara linealmente, necesito hacer un INNER JOIN pero las tablas de encuentran en diferentes bases de datos. Ya intente con nombreDB.dbo.nombretabla pero no me da ningún resultado.

Comment: qué significa "pero no me da ningún resultado"?, lanza error?, dónde ejecutaste el código que no te da resultados?...estás seguro que las tablas simplemente están en diferentes bases de datos o también son servidores diferentes?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tienes que fijarte a que base de datos estas apuntando o estas conectado si estas conectado digamos a la bd A para ingresar a la otra seria B.TABLA , yo tuve un error estaba ingresando a la bd A.tabla pero solo debi poner el nombre de la tabla y ala tabala B si tenia que ingresar B.TABLA lo mismo con los inner

Comment: mira un ejemplo SELECT * FROM todo_rh.tblPerfiles p left join spar_empleados s on p.idSolicitante=s.empleados_id left join spartodo_spar_bd.tblEscolaridad e on e.idEscolaridad=p.escolaridad WHERE p.idPerfil=$id

Comment: bueno ya funciono no utilice ese método pero me dieron la idea. Gracias.

Comment: Mejor metí los resultados en un arreglo bidimensional y con ayuda de 2 for los recorrí

Answer (score 0):

no me dio ningún error, comente este código e implemente el otro solo necesito que los precios sean diferentes y si no existe se imprima.  son el mismo servidor Usuario y contraseña. solo diferentes bases de datos.

```html
$sql = "SELECT SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1.ItemCode, SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.OITM.ItemCode, SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.OITM.ItemName, SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1.Price, SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1.PriceList, SBO_MASTERS.dbo.ITM1.Price,SBO_MASTERS.dbo.ITM1.ItemCode
        
FROM SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.OITM, SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1, SBO_MASTERS.dbo.OITM, SBO_MASTERS.dbo.ITM1 

WHERE SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1.ItemCode = SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.OITM.ItemCode 
AND SBO_MASTERS.dbo.OITM.ItemCode = SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1.ItemCode 
AND SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1.PriceList=1 

ORDER BY SBO_TRANSMISIONES.dbo.ITM1.ItemCode" ;
```

Lo pongo directo por para que se entienda de donde es cada dato.